Does Star Wars have the technology for Matrix-style simulations?
I was watching a video from the Youtube channel, Modern Day Eratosthenes and the Youtuber gave an example of Star Wars style prosthetics as the technology necessary to create a simulated reality like that of another sci-fi franchise, the Matrix. She also said that once our prosthetics are two-way (like Luke's), meaning we can touch something and experience a sensation back, that we should be able to create believable full-immersion simulations as well.
I honestly don't know if I believe this, but is there any indication that Star Wars tech is good enough to put someone in a simulation and have them not know they are in a fake world?

https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Simulation_room suggests nearly holodeck levels of holograms.

Related: Is there any presence of Virtual Reality in the Star Wars universe?
